# Append part does not work as expected when query are formed using SolrNet

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4, solrnet

I am working on a Solr for one commerce site, built using ASP.NET MVC, and using SolrNet for integration.

Everything works fine except the search handler component configuration for append query parameter. I am referring to this http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#Configuration

The specific thing I want to achieve is adding search query parameter using append part from the solr config files. Here is the handler configuration copied from my solr config.

```
 <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
  <int name="rows">1</int>
  <str name="field">Name</str>
  <str name="spellcheck">on</str>     
  <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.maxcollations">5</str> 
  <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.alternativetermcount">2</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.maxresultsforsuggest">5</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.maxcollationtries">5</str>
 </lst>
 <lst name="appends">
  <str name="qf">Vendor^1</str>
 </lst>

 <arr name="last-components">
  <str>spellcheck</str>
</arr>
```

This seems to work fine when I do query from a Solr admin interface. However, this doesn't work when my queries are being done through SolrNet. Here is both query:

Query which is working, done through Solr Admin:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/select?q=ABC&defType=edismax&qf=Name^8++ShortDescription^4++FullDescription^3+CategoryCopy^5+ManufacturerCopy^5+Sku^1+ChildSku^1+nGramContent+CustomProperties&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.q=ABC
```

The above query give me expected result with the product that I want.

Here is the query which is done from SolrNet, which is using same parameter, but I don't get result I want.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/select?q={!type%3dedismax+qf%3d%27Name^8++ShortDescription^4++FullDescription^3+CategoryCopy^5+ManufacturerCopy^5+Sku^1+ChildSku^1+nGramContent+CustomProperties%27+bq%3dStockAvailability%3atrue^1}%28ABC%29&start=0&rows=2&fq=Price%3a[0+TO+9999999999999]&spellcheck=true&spellcheck.q=ABC&spellcheck.collate=true
```

**Update**
Here is my Solrnet query:

```
private static ISolrOperations<MyClass> solr;                        
SolrQueryResults<MyClass> Results = new SolrQueryResults<MyClass>();   
Results = solr.Query(new LocalParams { { "type", "edismax" }, { "qf", "Name^" + nameWeight + "  Field1^" + Field1Weight + "  Field2^" + Field2Weight " }, { "bq", "InStock:true^"+ flag } });
```

This isn't working because may be it doesn't respect solr handler configuration for append parameter being done from solr config.

But why and how to fix this?

Comment: The difference is you're using `LocalParams` in Solrnet and you're not using it in the original query. The defaults/appends only apply to the exact same parameter in the querystring.

Comment: Hello Mauricio, Thank You for your response. Can you please advise me What can I do to get the result which I want using Solrnet.

Comment: Can you post your current SolrNet code?

Comment: Thank You Mauricio for your response. I have update my post. Can you please review it? Please Advice.

Comment: Instead of LocalParams use ExtraParams in QueryOptions to set `qf` and `defType`. See https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Querying.md#additional-parameters

Comment: Ok. I will try with this solution.